# JQuery slider: fade non active slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm working with a horizontal slider using JQuery, now I want something like on these examples below: the first picture show what I have so far. The second one shows want I want to do. The items that are 'none active' so that ones left and right from the center item, need to fade away a bit.

[image]

[image]

So anybody any idea on how to select the slides that are not active and help me accomplish this?

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
        <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider4">
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar10"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider4').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 300,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10,
        infiniteLoop: true
      });
});  
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `onSliderLoad` and the `onSlideAfter` option of bxSlider to add a class to the current slide:

```
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('.slider4 > div:not(.bx-clone)').eq(1).addClass('active');
    },
    onSlideAfter: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        $('.slide').removeClass('active');
        $($slideElement).next().addClass('active');        
    }
```

After you manage to add an 'active' class to the active slide, it's just a matter of CSS:

```
.slide:not(.active){
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

The above examples are from memory (pseudo-code) and are not intended as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: Your answer lead me to a solid solution, thanks for that! Only thing: the slide changes and then it takes a second to apply the class which causes a small delay to non-fade the active slide item

Comment: Instead of 'onSlideAfter' you can use 'onSlideBefore'. That will change the class before the slide transition. After that, If you add some css transitions, like 'transition: opacity 0.5s;' to your CSS, it should smoothly transition from opacity:1 to opacity:0.8